# Do we use "satis multum" + genitive to convey "a sufficient amount of"?

Tags: grammar-choice, word-choice, lingua-latina-per-se-illustrata, genitive, partitive-genitive

The following sentence comes from lines 126-128 of chapter XVI of *Lingua latina per se illustrata. Familia Romana*:

> Nāvis aquā implērī incipit, neque enim nautae satis multum aquae haurīre possunt.

By context, it seems to me that *satis multum*, followed by the genitive *aquae*, has some kind of partitive function, meaning, in this case, "a sufficient amount of water". But I'm not completely sure that my interpretation is correct. In a more general way, I would like to know if one should use the construction

> *satis multum* + genitive

to express "enough or a sufficient amount of something". Do we have to use "multum"? Or some other words are possible?

Comment: "neque enim nautae satis multum aquae haurīre possunt."
I was confused, too, but after reading the above I believe that 'multum' is used for emphasis. 'satis aquae' would be 'enough water' but 'satis multum aquae' I believe means 'a great enough amount of water.' However, I am stil not sure what part of speech 'multum' is. Is it a noun or an adverb; although I am leaning towards 'adverb'. Can anyone enlighten me?

Comment: Welcome to the site! If you want to ask a follow-up question, please write a new question (with a link to the appropriate old one) instead of writing an answer. We really stick to answers being about answering the question, not about continuing a discussion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, *satis multum aquae* means “enough water” or “a sufficient amount of water” (you cannot say “enough amount” in English because “enough” is an adverb).

This is not even a particularly fixed expression – Latin has a partitive genetive (*genetivus partitivus*), and while it is restricted to certain constructions, it can be used with many other words. A few important constructions are:

- Substantivized adjectives describing amounts like *multum* (much, many), *parvum* (little), *nihil* (nothing). This includes comparatives like *plus* and *minus* (*plus aquae* = “more water”).
- Nouns describing amounts like *pars* (part), *copia* (great amount), e.g. *copia ferramentorum* (a great amount of iron tools).
- Substantivized pronouns like *quis* or *nemo*, e.g. *quis nostrum* (who of us).
- Adverbs like *satis*, *parum* and *nimium*, i.e., it would also have been possible to say *satis aquae* (enough water).
- Comparatives, superlatives and ordinal numbers, e.g. *maior sororum* (the older of the sisters), *fortissimus militum* (the bravest of the soldiers), *decimus senatorum* (the tenth of the senators).

There are also some fixed expressions that are not easily classified, like *id temporis* (at the time) or *ubi gentium* (or *terrarum*; where in the world). For a relatively comprehensive list, see [Allen & Greenough](https://dcc.dickinson.edu/grammar/latin/genitive#partitive-genitive).

Comment: I understand. Is there any difference in meaning between *satis multum aquae* and *satis aquae*?

Comment: FWIW, *satis multum* only appears [once](https://latin.packhum.org/search?q=satis+multum) in PHI. I think *satis aquae* would be more normal.

Comment: @TKR *Satis aquae* would have been my intuition as well. Curious choice on Ørberg's part, then.

Comment: @Charo I cannot really see a real difference in meaning, no.