# What's the meaning of "paulum satis" in this sentence?

Tags: meaning, lingua-latina-per-se-illustrata, adverb

I've found the following sentence in an exercise (*pensum A*) at the end of chapter XXVI of *Lingua latina per se illustrata. Familia Romana*:

> Paulum satis est ad beātē vīvendum.

I don't understand the meaning of the expression *paulum satis* in this sentence. I've have previously found [similar constructions with *satis*](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/21638/) with a partitive function, but it doesn't seem to be the case here because any genitive is present. I had a look to the [Lewis and Short dictionary entry for *satis*](https://logeion.uchicago.edu/satis), but I wasn't able to find anything similar. Can anyone explain what this means?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*Paulum* alone is the subject here. A little is (*est*) enough (*satis*) for a good life (*ad beate vivendum*).